# Why do people oppose immigration ban?

Tags: united-states, immigration

Why do people oppose an immigration ban? What are their arguments?

Comment: I rewrote your question to fit into the neutrality criteria of this website.

Comment: Shouldn't this be much more specific? We today of course know what the OP is talking, as this thing is going on right now. But will anyone know in five years' time? Also, which immigration ban are we talking about specifically - the one enacted two days ago, temporary and targeting 7 countries? A potential future broader "muslim ban"? Immigration bans in general? What kind of arguments are we looking for here - general moral ones, the general talking points on the political spectrum, or legal ones?

Comment: I personally believe in open borders and that people can choose where to live (without regard to national borders) if they can provide for themselves. However, the question about immigration is a very broad one, probably too broad to answer as a single question on stackexchange. I actually liked your original version of the question better, since it provided more to respond to.

Answer (score 7):

Some people also just want to do right by humanity, regardless of nationality. You may be ok with *possibly* preventing a terrorist from entering the country, many people are opposed to *certainly* leaving many of these pro-American refugees to their fates and *absolutely* giving radical Islamists propaganda to fuel their recruiting pools. That last issue is compounded when preference or exceptions for specific religions is given.

Like many things in politics it is a question of priorities. The more nationalistic will disregard much of what happens beyond our borders since it doesn't apply directly to them, which is a valid world view. Specifically for the Trump administration, I think it makes sense from *his perspective* to take the action that he has while his new leadership assumes their roles and "gets up to speed" on the "actual" processes that are taking place, plus it is pretty much what he said he was going to do while he was campaigning.

Others disagree with the approach, and believe that *how* Trump is going about it could wind up doing much more harm to American interests than whatever good it may wind up doing or bad thing that it *may* prevent.

Comment: And it's not as if banning a nationality will suddenly "eradicate radical Islamic terrorism from the face of the earth". This ban will merely alienate middle eastern countries. Besides, wasn't it an American who walked into an elementary school and shot little kids? Or a movie theater? But sure, let's ban all Muslims because some of them choose to be bad people.

Comment: @AleksandrH This is a good point. Many people have argued that Saudi Arabia should be on the list of terror-exporting countries, and some may want to argue that _Belgium_ also has a history of exporting terrorists, yet it is a country that is also not on the list. Such a list may not actually be accurate unless _all_ countries are on it, _including_ the US.

Comment: There is also valid concern that it is fairly ineffective.  It's also not like we don't have vetting procedures in place.  I don't think that any of the people who have committed terrorist acts in the US are refugees from the banned countries.  And plenty of people see it as against US values to blanket turn away refugees.  You know, "“Give me your tired, your poor, 
Your huddled masses yearning to breathe free, The wretched refuse of your teeming shore. 
Send these, the homeless, tempest-tossed, to me: 
I lift my lamp beside the golden door.”

Comment: And then, it might be illegal: https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/27/opinion/trumps-immigration-ban-is-illegal.html

Comment: @AleksandrH This ban was signed into law to alienate middle eastern countries. Middle eastern terrorists primarily originate in... middle eastern countries. While the ban, which is only NINETY DAYS, is in place we can create a much better vetting process than was previously in place.

Comment: @rougon see my previous comment

Comment: @AmericanPatriot Your opinion is clear, but it has nothing to do with my comment. Part of the problem with both bans is that they don't demonstrate a need to do so.

Comment: @AmericanPatriot Tautologies do not an argument make. American terrorists originate in America, European terrorists originate in Europe, and Martian terrorists originate from Mars. On a different note, why keep referring to it as a _ban_ if it is meant to only be 90 days? Can we trust that after this period it will be lifted, and further actions won't be taken regardless of what changes are made to the vetting process?

Answer (score -1):

I would imagine people teaching English as a Second Language would oppose an immigration ban because it cuts down on their lively-hood. Although a ban on crime is impractical should there be no crime the police would protest.

People who hire immigrants because their labor costs are lower would oppose a ban.

People who are concerned that there are not enough new workers to support aging workers entering retirement would oppose an immigration ban. Over the last four decades there has been a dramatic switch from stay-at-home-moms with high birth rates to working moms with very low birth rates. Immigrants are more likely to have higher birth rates.

People not willing to do certain jobs like cleaning or manual labor would rather go to school or go on welfare and have an immigrant do those jobs. Although these people cannot control immigration they can subconsciously support it. This idea has the least merit and is listed last.

Answer (score -2):

> Why do people oppose an immigration ban? What are their arguments?

I think most people oppose ***illegal*** immigration, because it is illegal, dah!

some people oppose ***legal*** immigration on multiple grounds, like we need to take care of our own first, limited resources, population density, a drain on our existing financial and law enforcement resources, etc. or simply being a narrow-minded person.

I think ***legal*** immigration is needed and valuable to the US, from the perspective of us being an immigrant country, our economic needs for labor, and skilled workers -> I would argue that the various work-visa programs are detrimental to the countries that were exporting their well educated and most productive workers - the US got them for a song.

Obviously, now there are two tracks of discussions, one on ***illegal*** immigration (primarily on the southern border), and one on ***legal*** immigration from certain countries (security driven).

I think a discussion without distinction (of the two types of immigration) isn't helpful.

edit: in response to Jeff Lambert's point below:

> Some people also just want to do right by humanity, regardless of nationality.

I think the US immigration law needs an overhaul urgently, as it is too coarse to serve the citizens. I think citizens should be allowed to sponsor whoever they wish to into this country, subject to the following limitations:

1. the immigrants should not become a burden to the society. So to the extent that the immigrants draw upon public services, the citizen sponsor should reimburse the tax payers for that. We can build a reserve on the citizen sponsor day one to guard against credit risks.
2. the sponsor should be responsible for crimes committed by the immigrants as well.

To some extent, Trump is going down the first path, with the EOs this week. Taking on #2 requires a fundamental change to the law and may take a long time.

Such a system makes the citizens responsible for immigration, not the government. Those who love the refugees get to have as many of them in as they can, and those who hate the refugees don't have to pay for other people's hobby.

A win-win for all sides.