# Why is Trump's travel ban controversial? Why are so many people making a big deal out of it?

Tags: donald-trump, immigration

I don't understand why Trump's recent travel/immigration ban is considered to be so controversial, or why so many people are making a big deal out of it. There are only 7 or so countries affected by the ban, and they are all relatively small and impoverished. None of those countries are American allies, geopolitical heavy-weights, or economic powerhouses, so why do so many people seem to care so much? How would American citizens, business, and society be any different with a few less people from a few small countries?

Comment: Read some opposing viewpoints. This is really just a lazy question, at best, and at worse, just a rant asking for debate.

Comment: If I may, downvoting and ignoring/scolding him won't solve anything. The problem won't go away if you refuse to talk about it.

Comment: @Ryan G How about you add ELI5 in front of your question, signal people that you simply want to know why radical nationalism is a bad thing. After all doesn't it indeed look as such a juicy red apple with the pro points you mention? >>Why<< could it be a bad thing to become the nation version of a morality-devoid selfish sociopath? That's what I'd want to see answered.

Comment: @DeveloperDoge, are you saying that anything short of totally open borders with no controls or restrictions on who enters is radical nationalism?  I'm not aware of any country in the history of the planet that comes close to that standard (at least that survived long enough to make the history books).

Comment: @fixer1234 Because that's what America had before the ban right? `"open borders with no controls or restrictions" ` Or no wait, maybe that's just your words.

Comment: Though I could've written just nationalism, people often forget what's further down that road once you take it. Radical nationalism does correctly represent that which we get if he starts adding more "pro points" for going in that direction, he's only given a few examples to support his question, and none of them are wrong if you think about it, they just miss the big picture of why we don't do it.

Comment: @DeveloperDoge the temporary restrictions have a negligible impact on the total flow of immigrants, even during its term.  Don't you think it's a stretch to say that this changes the character of the country?  You balked at my characterization of no controls.  If we have controls they are always adjusted to define who is accepted at any given time (that's what was there before).  It isn't clear how this tweak is so different from what has been done routinely in the past.

Comment: If they have "such negligible impact"... why disgrace your country in the eyes of others over it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do people oppose immigration ban?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14938/why-do-people-oppose-immigration-ban)

Comment: Because some people want to show their charity towards others by inviting them to other people's homes, communities and cities.

Comment: Others wanted to use the issue as a political tools to drum up support for their causes, to strengthen their power and weaken their political enemies. They don't care about what will happen to the country or its people.

Comment: @DeveloperDoge "the problem won't go away if you refuse to talk about it": but the purpose of this site is not to solve problems by talking about them.

Answer (score 6):

"Keep all your tired, your poor, Your huddled masses yearning to breathe free, The wretched refuse of your teeming shore. Send these, the homeless, tempest-tossed, to someone else: I snuff my lamp beside the golden door."

There, does that sound about right to you?

(P.S. credits to jcrreddit)

Comment: That sounds great! Here, in America, we have plenty of OUR own poor, homeless and destitute citizens to care for. Until we can completely and unequivocally end hunger, homelessness, and poverty for all American citizens what business do we have giving American resources away to non-citizens?

Comment: @ryanG your irony detector is on the fritz.

Comment: **Ideologies** of equality, kindness & compassion, of striving to be good human beings. Ideologies whose influence on decision making and our form as a society, has given us a competitive edge throughout thousands of years of competition against other populations with different beliefs.These ideologies are prevalent among the American people, they drive the emotional reactions and idea's of what's right and wrong, including on trumps ban.

Comment: @ryanG immigrants fuel economic expansion. That's why the Declaration of Independence included a complaint that King George wasn't allowing adequate immigration. So the idea that reducing immigration will somehow create an economic benefit is completely backward. Sure, a few immigrants will end up taking some government benefits, but the vast majority of them are determined, motivated people who want to enter the country so they can work and make money.

Comment: @phoog - that's an empty and wrong generalization. Different types of immigrants have different (and complicated) effects on economics (from trivial such as immigrant groups that almost entirely use more public resources than produce economic output if you count schools and medicine; to more complicated such as detrimental effect on social cohesion which has negative effects on economy as per research). If you ignore that, you do sound like open borders zealot that other answer comments claimed do not exist. I'm ignoring the terrorism downsides here, too.

Comment: @user4012 it's not a generalization, it's a description of the overall effects of immigration.  If you want to refine immigration policy so it can do a better job of excluding those who would commit crimes or be a burden on the state, that's one thing, but excluding criminals by stopping immigration altogether, even from a small subset of countries, is cutting off your nose to spite your face.

Answer (score 1):

1. Some people want open borders with absolutely no restrictions.  Anything that even temporarily restricts anyone from freely showing up is considered Un-American.  See DeveloperDoge's answer.
2. Aside from this specific issue, some people are seeking to undermine and obstruct Trump from carrying out his presidential duties.  I don't believe there is any contention on this point, but I can create a list of examples to illustrate if so.
3. Trump is a bit of a loose cannon when he speaks and has a habit of saying stupid things (especially before his staff forced him to use a teleprompter to minimize this).  Early in his campaign he misspoke and mentioned the term "Muslim ban", which he quickly corrected.  The people mentioned in point #2 have used that to characterize the temporary travel restrictions and vetting review as a religious ban; another way to undermine Trump and sow dissent.  The actual order can be viewed here: https://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2017/01/27/executive-order-protecting-nation-foreign-terrorist-entry-united-states
4. The action is intended to be proactive to avoid foreseeable risks such as Europe has dealt with, which is why it is focused on current terror hot spots with little ability to vet refugees.  Some people have raised issues that our previous terror attacks were perpetrated by people from countries other than those, so the refugees of those countries are being targeted without a valid reason.
5. Trump made a decision to execute the order without advance public notice, weighing the inconvenience to people in flight at the time against the likelihood of advance notice creating a flood of people trying to beat the order.  In addition, the implementation created some initial confusion about coverage for people who already had valid visas and green cards.  A little over 100 people were affected, some delayed at the airport and a few were returned home.
6. Some temporary restraining orders were sought against the action to allow judicial review based on issues such as the inconvenience it would cause to the travelers and "irreparable harm" the delay would cause to various constituents.  That has been touted as proof that the action was unconstitutional, further adding to the narrative.  CNN, which is clearly not in Trump's corner, published an article on these legal challenges, with links: http://www.cnn.com/2017/02/06/politics/9th-circuit-court-of-appeals-trump-travel-ban/  To quote a headline from the article:

> Not a constitutional challenge

Again, to cite an article with clearly no Trump bias, another CNN article summarizing the issues: http://www.cnn.com/2017/01/28/politics/donald-trump-travel-ban/

Comment: This is a rant not an answer. And you are literally just asking for downvotes.

Comment: But, for the record, the downvotes have nothing to do with 'the narrative popular on this site'. It has to do with answers not being just partisan rants. Which this one is. There are very *real* legal and policy concerns about the travel ban shared by people on both sides of the aisle. To brush it off as 'everyone is just picking on Trump' is about as partisan as you can get.

Comment: @blip, are you asserting that there is no organized campaign to undermine Trump?  I can certainly list endless examples.  I have seen plenty of false issues that others are free to raise, but the actual order is nothing resembling the claims.  Would it improve the answer to post a link to the order or include it here?  The same with the TROs.

Comment: there is *always* an opposition out to undermine the opponent. That's politics. There are much more *specific* issues with this particular incident, however, that go above and beyond the typical "I'm right, you're wrong" rhetoric. There's a context we're all working with here. It's not jsut the order. It's Bannon. It's the tweets. It's the timing. It's all the other things he's done. You have to look at the bigger picture in terms of what makes something controversial.

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to improve the answer, though. It's just a really lazy question to even ask in the first place. That said, if you want to try, I'd remove the last paragraph where you essentially are just asking everyone to downvote your answer.

Comment: @blip, is this better?

Comment: With regard to point 1 I am unaware of anyone advocating totally open borders, though I can imagine there are fringe crackpots out there who do. Opposition to the travel ban is not restricted to fringe crackpots, however.  Do you have any evidence of mainstream politicians who advocate totally open borders without restrictions?

Comment: "inconvenience to people" - People in flight thought they were moving to the USA, based on their valid, approved, vetted visas. They quit their jobs, sold their homes and all possessions they weren't bringing with them, paid for flights to the USA, and then were sent back to a place where they had nothing left. Does that sound like a little "inconvenience"?

Comment: Not downvoting but this is lacking. There is a good answer on Law SE that outlines many more real reasons the law is being opposed.

Comment: @jalynn2, my understanding is that out of several hundred thousand people, a little over 100 were actually affected.  The vast majority were simply delayed at the airport.  Something like half a dozen were sent back, and not every one of those was in the situation you describe.  One such case was highlighted on TV.  It was disconcerting for them, but the situation was turned around and they returned here.  So granted, for a few people it was more than a simple inconvenience.  But that was not representative, and I suspect that the system routinely manages to screw things up in similar ways.

Comment: @zabeus, can you post a link?  I scanned the first several pages there and spotted only a closed question with no answers.

Comment: @fixer1234 Was posting on mobile earlier and couldn't find it then. http://law.stackexchange.com/a/16793

Comment: @zabeus, thanks.  That looks like a pretty comprehensive list, but it addresses what the potential legal issues are.  The question was focused on why people are making a big deal over the action.  It would be great of people were really focused on the legal issues.  But I think the vast majority who are making an issue of the order 1) aren't familiar with those issues, 2) have been stirred into a frenzy about fake issues, or 3) don't really care too much about the specific details (Trump is bad for a zillion reasons; whether specific ones are accurate doesn't change the big picture).